# Basic multi-threading in C / C++ -- hints, advice, tutorial, some direction?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I would like to learn how to build a multi-threaded application, but I don't even really know where to start.

How do most people implement multi-threading? Do they use the boost library? Is there some other way to do it? (using standard C / C++)

I understand the concept, but totally have no idea where to even start to actually learn how to do it. Can anyone recommend anything?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9ha0zh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx  <--- Are these standard C++, or some Microsoft-only implementation?

Am I correct that the multithreading libraries are contained in the Windows API?
I found an example on MSDN (
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esszf9hw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and the functions it uses (ReleaseMutex, etc) seem to be in windows.h. Is this what most people are using when they do Windows programming?

Comment: there is no standard C/C++ threads.  boost threads is next best thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415994/boost-thread-tutorials.  C++0x does have threads if you want to go that route.

Comment: I was doing some reading the other day, and it appears that Microsoft's Managed C++ has made some serious deviations from the C++ standard that might trick you up.  Be careful that the MSDN documentation isn't talking about Managed C++ and not true standardized C++.

Comment: Feel free to have a look at my Tetris project that uses multithreading excessively (mostly for the sake of self-education): http://code.google.com/p/tetris-challenge/ .

Answer (score 3):

Boost library is a cross-platform way of using threads.

Most people use [winapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads). pthreads was originally used on POSIX systems but there is a port of it for mingw allowing its use on windows too.

I'd recommend using boost if you absolutely need cross-platform solution, or already have boost libraries linked. If you are developing for windows or POSIX, use winapi or pthreads correspondingly.

Comment: Just use boost - Boost.Thread and Boost.Bind are my two favorite friends this week.

Comment: I've used [winpthreads](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) with MSVC too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a simple performance boost for in your application through multi-threading [OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/) is a simple library that will allow your program to scale across multiple cores, requiring only #pragma placement in your code to parallelize blocks of code or loops, with additional options to weak specific performance.

This doesn't easily allow for coarse parallelism like a GUI/processing/IO division in the application, but does allow for easily visible multi-threading performance boosts on multi-core machines in heavy number-crunching.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never before dealt with multithreading, i'd suggest you work yourself through a tutorial like [this one on codeproject](http://faq.programmerworld.net/programming/win32-multithreading-and-synchronization.html) to get started.