# Threading in C/C++, any standard?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic multi-threading in C / C++ — hints, advice, tutorial, some direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402916/basic-multi-threading-in-c-c-hints-advice-tutorial-some-direction)

I would like to start using threads and learn about threading in C/C++.

Is there any standard library? else which are the most used or which would you recommend for a beginner in threading?

Comment: [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) is standard in c++11

Comment: Do you really need it to work with C as well as C++ ?

Comment: the pthread library is used for C programs: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Well, [POSIX threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) *is* one standard :)

Comment: There's no such thing as C/C++!

Comment: Both C++11 and C11 have threading functionality in their standard libraries. The are however not the same, in fact the API is _very_ different, so you can't use C++ threads from C, but the other way around should work but I wouldn't consider it good C++.

Comment: OpenMP is supported by most compilers: http://openmp.org/wp/

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu - yes, it's a possible duplicate of that question, but the answers there are wrong (well, charitably, outdated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On most platforms you need OS kernel support to do threading in a performant way (that can for example use multiple CPU cores at once).  (I will note that it is possible to cooperative threading in userland, but this is atypical these days.  See `makecontext` on Linux for example)

**Kernel Calls:**

On Linux and Mac, *pthreads* api is thin wrapper of `clone` syscall.

On Windows, Windows API `CreateThread` and friends.

**Standard Librires (that wrap kernel calls):**

On C11, [`<threads.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)

On C++11, [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and friends.

**3rd Party Libraries (that wrap the above):**

apr (apache runtime)

boost::thread

Qt

many others

Comment: [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) added threading in the `<threads.h>` header file to the C language.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11 there is [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

Before that, all solutions were plattform-specific.

Comment: What's the implementation status of `std::thread`?

Comment: I'm using it on `g++ 4.7 -std=gnu++11`

Answer (score 2):

I found the Boost threads library to be good, and it's available for any platform that Boost supports, which is quite a few.

[The Boost.Threads Library](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-boostthreads-library/184401518?cid=dobbs-callout-mostpop)

[Threading with Boost - Part I: Creating Threads](http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html)

Answer (score 2):

My two cents, based in my own experience:

1) As a first step, pthreads (a POSIX for C) and I used the link as Hunter McMillen  [computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads](http://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads). It is concise and worth reading.

2) After that in C++ I went to the boost interface (look for ). I recommend to read the book C++ Concurrency in Action (http://www.manning.com/williams/).
The advantage of this is that the book

1. in my view effectively introduces you to threads
2. You can use boost which is easy to install and compile
3. And as the author states, you will get used as well to the new standard C+11 (since, as the author claims, the boost implementation is quite similar to the new standard).

Comment: +1 for the very nice pthreads link.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has std::thread in its newest incarnation (C++11). Otherwise, Qt is frequently used for a lot of stuff, or boost::thread if you don't need all that other stuff in Qt or don't like the licensing issue.

C doesn't have a standard threading.

Comment: C11 added `<threads.h>`, just like C++11.

Comment: `<threads.h>` in C11 is optional.

Comment: `std::thread` in C++11 is also optional.  Just like `std::vector`.

Comment: @MooingDuck. Optional in C11 case is different than optional in C++11 case. A C11 implementation is allowed not to provide <threads.h> at all.

Comment: @jons34yp: I checked the spec, you're mostly right.  Hosted implementations must have all the headers.  Freestanding implementations are only required to have `new`, `typeinfo`, `exception`, `initializer_list`, `type_traits`, and `atomic`, and a few C headers

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using OpenMP; it is very easy to use.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/

Example: Distribute calculations of elements in an array between threads:

```
float array[i];
#pragma omp parallel for // This is the important bit
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    array[i] = Compute(i); 
}
```

How it works:
A number of threads are spawned (you can set the number, it should default to the number of cores you have), and each thread executes a section of the loop.

ie: If N = 100, and you have 2 threads, then thread 1 executes the for loop with i = 0 to 49, thread 2 executes with i = 50 to 99.

You should be careful with multithreading. For example, if the later elements in the array are dependent upon earlier elements, the final array will be useless because these later elements may be calculated first.

You will need to supply -fopenmp to gcc, or the #pragma will be considered a comment, and ignored (ie: The main thread will do everything).

Comment: I've never found an application for OpenMP.  It doesn't scale at all and it's very difficult to debug.  The only place it seems useful is in a "hello world" threading example, beyond that a threading library seems far superior.  Just my 2c.

Comment: It depends on what you want to use it for. It is very easy to use OpenMP to speed up serial code which has a lot of long computation loops. I often use it in games or simulations for updating the position/velocity of objects. I'd probably use pthreads if I needed more lower level control though.

Comment: You can just use an Executor service model on top of a ThreadPool type.  Every framework has this (see `std::future`, `std::promise` for example), or it is easy to write your own.  Trying to bolt on language features through pragmas creates a mess in my view.